# How to extract SVF related files to load that model into Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

How can I obtain the essential SVF files and their associated components required for loading into the Autodesk Forge Viewer from a custom server or Amazon S3? My objective is to access a model within the Forge Viewer using a custom server. I'm in search of a guide that offers step-by-step instructions or a link to an article that provides this information.

Answer (score 0):

SVF asset can vary depending on the input file format. For more details on how to download the SVF (or just some of its parts), take a look at the [forge-convert-utils](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils) library, specifically the [SvfDownloader](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils/blob/develop/src/svf/downloader.ts). It parses the actual SVF file to identify all the additional assets (e.g., geometry files, textures, property database files, etc.) that need to be downloaded as well.